# How to Share installed app?

Tags: android

I am developer and i try to share installed app in my phone, but crash app when used below code .

```
Uri packageURI = Uri.parse("package:" + "ir.divar");
Intent share = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SHARED, packageURI);
startActivity(share);
```

Comment: can you post the logcat means what type of error it is coming

Comment: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.MEDIA_SHARED dat=package:ir.divar }

Comment: The answer is not someone else?

Answer (score 0):

First, that `Intent` action is not designed for use with `startActivity()`, as you can tell by reading [the documentation for that action](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_MEDIA_SHARED). That action is used for broadcasts.

Second, that `Intent` action is not for sharing content, as you can tell by reading [the documentation for that action](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_MEDIA_SHARED). It is broadcast by the system, related to mounting and unmounting external storage, particularly on Android 1.x/2.x devices. Use `ACTION_SEND` to share content.

Third, few if any apps will be able to share something identified by a `Uri` with a `package` scheme. You would need to find the file path for your app's APK file and share it that way, though I do not know if this is possible.

Comment: The answer is not someone else?